# "PowerShell on Target Machines" task fails with an error in TFS 2017\Azure Dev Ops

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to run a PowerShell script present on one of the azure server using the "PowerShell on Target Machines" Task in my TFS build definition, but the task fails with the below error.

> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: The running command
>   stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or
>   common parameter is set to Stop: The specified path, file name, or
>   both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260
>   characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
>   --->

I have copied the script in F drive but it still gives path too long error, not able to find any solution for the same.

Does anyone know what would be the reason?

[image: Screenshot of PowerShell on Target machine task]

Added script code as well for reference,

GetLatestDebugOutput.ps1

```
$DebugBuildOutput = "F:\Drops\econNextGen\SecurityScan\19.0"
$Dest = "F:\Drops\econNextGen\SecurityScan\Debug Build Output"


Remove-Item "$Dest\*" -Recurse -Force

#Code to Copy Common-App Debug Build
$Dir= $DebugBuildOutput + "\econNextGen-Common-App-Debug\"
$Latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$FolderPath= $Dir +$Latest.Name 
Copy-Item -Path $FolderPath $Dest –Recurse -force


#Code to Copy Main-App Debug Build
$Dir= $DebugBuildOutput + "\econNextGen-MAIN-APP-Debug\"
$Latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$FolderPath= $Dir +$Latest.Name 
Copy-Item -Path $FolderPath $Dest –Recurse -force
```

Comment: Could you share the .ps1 file you trying to run or target machines ? 
And/Or the build settings page screenshot?

Comment: From my experience executing TFS with powershell this line of code would not appear if your script path was wrong or unacceptable( I mean this ;
The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop )

This is why the script inside your file could be an important case

Comment: @JimErginbash I have shared the ps script and powershell on target machine task for reference.

Answer (score 1):

First suggest you directly RDP to remote target machine and check if you are able to run the same script in it. This will narrow down if the issue related to your tfs build definition and environment.

For environment, make sure you have met all **prerequisites** of this [PowerShell on Target Machines task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops). And you have qualified powershell version installed.

Actually the error message is pretty straight forward, and so is **the key point you should pay attention to: make sure you're not using paths that are too long** or using an invalidly path. If apply for all folder and files.

Besides, try starting the [build with diagnostics\debug enabled](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/) with `system.debug=true` and see if you can get any meaningful output for future troubleshooting.

Comment: I am able to RDP and also able to run the script, infact the script was created on the target server itself. All the prerequisite are enabled by configuring WinRM HTTPS protocol on the azure servers and opened the port 5986 on it. Previously i.e. at the beginning the path was "F:\Drops\econNextGen\SecurityScan\GetLatestDebugOutput.ps1", which i latter updated to "F:\GetLatestDebugOutput.ps1" after getting path too long error. but still it didn't succeed and continue to gives this error.  Also, i executed the build with debug mode but still got nothing meaningful.

Comment: Hi All, I believe the issue is with the PowerShell script, because now i tried executing another demo script and it got successfully executed without any error. But if i try to run the previous ps script manually it does work fine but fails with CI PowerShell task on target machine.

Comment: @SRP Thanks for your quick response.Yeah, according to your description, it so, this should related to your script. After go through your script again, I was wondering if it's related to this sentence `$FolderPath= $Dir +$Latest.Name `.  `$Dir= $DebugBuildOutput + "\econNextGen-MAIN-APP-Debug\"` and `$DebugBuildOutput = "F:\Drops\econNextGen\SecurityScan\19.0"`, you have three level. Please try to short your FolderPath. It may do the trick.

Comment: actually the above code was correct but the issue was during copying one of the file whose path was too long for PowerShell to copy and due to this it was throwing the error as "it cannot not find the path". This was the file which it was unable to copy becasue of its long path. "F:\Drops\teconNextGen\SecurityScan\19.0\teconNextGen-Main-WEB-HTML5-Debug\teconNextGen-Main-WEB-HTML5-Debug_20191112.1\app\inventory\inventory-model\tecon-inventory-model-page-activity-view-layout-tab\recon-inventory-model-page-activity-view-layout-tab.component.js"

Comment: So, to resolve this i simply created a zip of all the files i needed to copy and then copied the zip to the target folder.